# StarUML UseCase diagram for creating the Hangman game

Tags: diagram, use-case, staruml

As the title says I have problems creating a simple use case diagram for the game Hangman. The rules are simple, the computer generates a word, it gives you the length and the first and last letter, and you have 9 tries to guess the word. So far I've done this :[Hangman Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7z8q.jpg)

The problem is that this is my first diagram, and I think I didn't I put everything in order and the player is associated with more actions. Every suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have it very detailed.

Also there seam to be misunderstanding of Actors definition. Quote:

> Actors. An actor is a person, organization, or **external system** that
> plays a role in one or more interactions with your system.

Your Computer actor is in fact **internal** system therefore should not be modeled as an actor.

Also for the use cases

> A use case describes a sequence of actions that provide something of
> **measurable value** to an actor.

The point here is about providing measurable value.

I suggest you to try to change it when you think more about these UML principles.

EDIT:

Nice UML example for game is here: http://xnagamedevelopment.blogspot.cz/2009/03/use-case-diagram.html

Interesting discussion on game industry vs uml is here: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/192120-uml-for-games/

That discussion might not help with your assignment, though.

Comment: OK, but if I take away Computer as an actor, who will generate the word ?

Comment: Is generating the word use case valuable to someone?

Comment: Look at this: http://vlssit.iitkgp.ernet.in/isad/v_media/images/theory/03/use_case_1.png  You might ask the same question - who will gather the books into the bookstore? The point is there might be a missing Actor if the use case of gathering the books is valuable to someone (e.g. bookstore manager). In gaming system you might have someone called Game manager who is interested to know about word and players statistics. But I doubt the Computer cares :)

Comment: Ok so I'll change the computer to Creator/Admin. And after that how can I show that it gives you the length of the word and the first and last letter ?

Comment: For Admin you might have use cases such as: populate word library, read word playing statistics, read players statistics, ban player, etc. Giving the length of word and 2 letters is rather the value for player - you can call it "View initial hint"